# Mask UI Image/RawImage

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I recently encountered a problem with UI. I opened a new 2D project and created a canvas with a GameObject with a Image component. I then added a sprite by right-clicking `Assets > Create > Sprites > Circle`. This added a circle sprite to my Assets folder.

The problem is when I choose the Source Image for the Image component as the circle, it still displays as a rectangle.
[image: Screenshot showing white rectangle]

The circle sprite is imported as Sprite for Texture Type.

This problem also happens with the other shapes, such as triangle.

I am using Unity 5.6.0b9 Personal. Build target is PC, Mac, Linux Standalone.

I am probably missing something very simple. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. Circle and all other type of Sprites under the *Assets > Create > Sprites* Menu are **only** made to work with `SpriteRenderers`. This would have worked if you used SpriteRenderer from *GameObject*--> *2D Object*--> *Sprite*. They do not work with the UI.

For the UI, this has to be done with the [Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Mask.html) component. Just get any round image then use it to cut out circle from your target square image.

1. Create a UI Image called "TargetSquare" which is the image you want to round.
2. Duplicate it then name this "MaskCircle" and then resize it to make it smaller than the "TargetSquare" until that circle shape is what you want.
3. Make the "MaskCircle" object to be the parent of the "TargetSquare" object then use [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSWEJ.png) round Sprite I made as it's source image.
4. Attach the `Mask` component to the "MaskCircle" object.

Done. Your "TargetSquare" object will have the shape of the "MaskCircle" object.

If you get jagged edges, select the sprite you used for the "MaskCircle" image and then make sure that Mipmap is disabled.

[image]

Comment: That's strange... regular PNGs work fine for both SpriteRenderer and Image. Why wouldn't they give the built-in sprites compatibility?

Comment: Why? It says "Sprite" clearly. Originally, this was made for `SpriteRenderer` to create many shapes easily. Unity's UI/Image is new and was just released few years ago. Unity's UI/Image is different from Sprite and SpriteRenderer. It is for displaying UI only. If you are using a 2D character or 2D world, you should be using  `SpriteRenderer`. UI/Image has its **own** solution for giving fake shape to Images and that's the `Mask`. It allows you to do this in runtime. You can't with Sprites.

Comment: As for why it's not supported, the fake sprite uses placeholder sprites and algorithm to generate that shape but that's not how the UI works. That's why its not supported.UI uses directl OpenGL/stencil to make it work so that it will be very fast. I am sure Unity wants you to use Mask as that makes more sense. That menu is actually called "SpriteCreator" and you can read more about it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteCreator.html)

Comment: can u help me in Unity Creating Screen Transitions Like vertical & horizontal  Transitions.

Comment: @shankarkn Create new Unity question about that and explain what exactly you want to do and what you have tried. I will take a look and see if I can do that.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is bug, in  unity 5.6.1f1 same story.
Just try to download new version unity 5.6.2f. I dont know, that bug is fixed or not.

Or

Use some image editor, for example photoshop.

P.S. My fail, all ok, it works on SpriteRenderer component. Unity generates white square, and in this sprite properties setting Sprite Mode to Polygon and creates some shape using vertices.

Comment: It's not a bug and updating Unity won't solve that either. Maybe Unity will add that to the UI in the feature.

Comment: Yes, my fail, but maybe he want just draw circle, without use mask.

Comment: The menu op menitoned does notdraw circle. It creates round sprites which can be replicated with the mask if you want to use the UI to do this. If OP does not want to use the UI then he should use `SpriteRenderers` like I mentioned because that's what supports everything in the *Assets > Create > Sprites > Circle* munu.

Comment: @nipercop Yes, I do want to draw just a circle, but a mask is the only way to do that.

Comment: @yummypasta be careful, mask component takes a lot DrawCalls, if you creating mobile game.